# CakePHP 3.x | Cookies reading from subdomain

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

I'm having problem when reading cookies on subdomain, which has been written on main one.

**Main domain**

```
$this->Cookie->configKey('agent', [
     'domain' => '.domain.com'
]);

$this->Cookie->write('agent', $user['id']);
```

**Reading from SubDomain**

```
$_cookie_user = $this->Cookie->read('agent')
```

When i'm `dump($_cookie_user)` - it's showing me `""`.

I have tried to disable encryption, but when it tries to get value - it was throwing an exception, because empty data cannot be decoded.

What steps should i take to solve this issue?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. but sub-domain cookies are only available on that sub-domain. You can set generic domain cookies that are accessible across all sub-domains eg `my` is a subdomain of `my.domain.com`. but if you set a cookin on `domain.com` you can access it on all sub domains.

Comment: @JasonJoslin, actually i'm setting up this stuff for all subdomains and it doesn't work on them

Comment: Have you debugged the response, ie checked whether the server responds with a cookie (use your browsers network console or a debugging proxy)? If it's being set, does the cookie look like expected? And have you debugged that the client is actually sending the cookied to the subdomain on subsequent requests? If so, does it send the cookie (content) that you'd expect?